# Deploying SSAS Tabular Model in a multi Domain environment

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, tabular

Using SQL Server 2016 Standard, VS 2015, SSAS Tabular model created with an Integrated Work space level 1200

We have a multi Domain environment, I moved the Model files over and ran the SSAS deployment wizard success, and can access the model on SSMS while on the box(Remote Desktop/VM)

How can I get it so I can develop (SSRS/power BI/Excel/web app) on my local machine, when I attempt to connect SSMS it Caches my windows user and I cant change it to match the credentials on the box(VM)

Whats the easiest authentication setup for tabular in a multi domain environment

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You must obviously be adding a DataSource to your report already. If you go to the DataSource properties there is a credentials tab on the left. Here to you can specify to use a username and password. You can specify the domain in the user field. Make sure you click the "Use as Windows credentials" checkbox as well. That aught to do it.

Comment: I should note that this credential information will be saved in the report. I recommend you use a dedicated access account for the login info. This also applies for shared datasets you may have available on the SSRS server.

Comment: I haven't been successful with this approach yet, 

I have a couple questions what account should i be using I have a Windows account on the VM, then i have a windows account on my local machine (they are different and on a separate domain(the tabular model was built locally)), also im using server credentials in the data sources in the model 

Also how would i do this in SSMS i see no impersonation option ?

Thank you sorry for the slow response

Comment: You'll need to use an account that has access to the SQL Server. If it is a domain user, include the domain (or machine name in the case of no domain) in the username (domain\username). Make sure you are getting to the correct screen. Right click dataset, click properties. Then Credentials tab on the left. SQL Server 2016 DOES have check boxes for using windows credentials and impersonation.